# Oracle virtual column referencing another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table `TABLE1` with column `COL_TAB1`.

```
select * from TABLE1:
 COL_TAB1
|    1   |
|    2   |
|    3   |
```

And another table `TABLE2` with `COL_TAB2` and references the first column `COL_TAB1`

```
select * from TABLE2:
 COL_TAB2  |  COL_TAB1
| val1     |     1
| val2     |     2
| val2     |     3
```

Is it possible to add a virtual column on table1 so i would get the same result as the following query:

```
select 
    t1.COL_TAB1, 
    (select t2.COL_TAB2 from TABLE2 t2 where t2.COL_TAB1 = t1.COL_TAB1)
from TABLE1 t1
```

I tried :

```
alter table TABLE1 add (
    SOME_COL_NAME as (select t2.COL_TAB2 from TABLE2 t2 where t2.COL_TAB1 = COL_TAB1)
)
```

But it gives me `ORA-00936: missing expression`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oracle's [documentation on virtual columns](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php) states it rather clearly, you can only reference columns in the same table;

> The expression used in the virtual column definition has the following
>   restrictions:
>
> - It cannot refer to another virtual column by name.
> - ***It can only refer to columns defined in the same table.***
> - If it refers to a
>     deterministic user-defined function, it cannot be used as a
>     partitioning key column.
> - The output of the expression must be a
>     scalar value. It cannot return an Oracle supplied datatype, a
>     user-defined type, or LOB or LONG RAW.

As @JoeStefanelli states, your best bet to do what you want is to [create a view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm).

Answer (score 2):

[Creating a view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/create-view.html) would probably be your best bet in this case.

```
CREATE VIEW vwTable1and2
AS
    SELECT t1.COL_TAB1, t2.COL_TAB2
        FROM TABLE1 t1
            INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
                ON t1.COL_TAB1 = t2.COL_TAB1
```

Comment: that makes sens, but in a slightly related matter, do you know if hibernate handles views as it does for tables ?

Comment: @jidma: Sorry, I've not worked with hibernate, so I can't say.

Answer (score 0):

**That's not an answer. This is there to prevent you to test this idea that doesn't work:**

I've tried to to make the joint inside a function and use the function in the definition of the virtual column.

```
CREATE TABLE A(
a1 integer,
a2 integer
);

CREATE TABLE B(
b1 integer,
b2 integer
);

CREATE FUNCTION f (arg IN integer)
    RETURN INTEGER
IS
  ret integer;
BEGIN
    select B.b2 into ret from A join B on A.a1=B.b1
    where A.a1=arg;
    RETURN ret;
END;

alter TABLE A add (
    a4 as (f(a1))
);
```

> ORA-30553: The function is not deterministic

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0e49d974eedf0fc97420967f1b33b2b7)

But it doesn't work. You need deterministic functions. (it excludes the function using queries in the database)